# $f$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z_0$,What is the order of pole of $f′$ at $z_o$?

Tags: roots, residue-calculus, singularity

[image]

I have done upto this.I do not have any clue on how to proceed further.
Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Use Latex. You said that $f(z) = (z-z_0)^k g(z)$ where $g(z_0) \ne 0$ means $f'(z) = (z-z_0)^{k-1} ( g'(z) (z-z_0)+ k g(z))=(z-z_0)^{k-1} h(z) $ where $h(z_0) \ne 0$...